# How to get UDDIPublisher permission for a user in wso2 to run JAXR sample

Tags: wso2

I am trying to run JAXR sample in Governance Registry in WSO2 which deals with UDDI support.It say before running I should add a user with UDDIPublisher Permission to  scoutv3.properties file .I dont know which username and password I need to add to this file in order to run the sample.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The role which user belongs to  should have UDDIPublisher permission to publish a service to UDDI registry. Therefore you should add a valid username and password in scoutv3.properties file (instead of root/root).

To tryout this sample you can use the admin/admin for userid and password. (admin has all the permissions)